# How do I set up configuration variables in Tesseract to better recognize code?

Tags: tesseract

I want to use Tesseract to recognize code. It is said on their website that I can disable dictionaries by setting both of the configuration variables `load_system_dawg` and `load_freq_dawg` to `false`.

However I haven't been able to do it correctly.

```
$ tesseract img.jpg output.txt --oem 0 -c load_system_dawg=0 load_freq_dawg=0
read_params_file: Can't open load_freq_dawg=0
Error: Tesseract (legacy) engine requested, but components are not present in /usr/share/tesseract-ocr/4.00/tessdata/eng.traineddata!!
Failed loading language 'eng'
Tesseract couldn't load any languages!
Could not initialize tesseract.
```

Any ideas on best ways to handle it?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, get eng.traineddata with the legacy engine or other OCR engine value (OEM).

Next, read the output of `tesseract --help-extra` carefully:

```
  -c VAR=VALUE          Set value for config variables.
                        Multiple -c arguments are allowed.
```